# getting several variables from one result (one for the first letter, one for the second, the rest from the rest of them)

Tags: macos, scripting, applescript

It's very straightforward to make one variable the result returned from a dialog in applescript, but is it possible to use the first and second letter as two separate variables and the rest of the result returned from the dialog as a third?  Below there's a code example with what I want to do and approximately where I think I want to do it.

```
    tell application "Finder"
        activate
        display dialog "newNameOfFolderDialogue" default answer "x"
            set categoryOne to [THE FIRST LETTER OF] (text returned of result)
            set categoryTwo to [THE SECOND LETTER OF] (text returned of result)
            set categoryThree to [THE REMAINING LETTERS OF] (text returned of result)
end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't be simpler:

```
set theText to text returned of result
set categoryOne to the first character of theText
set categoryTwo to the second character of theText
set categoryThree to (text 3 thru (length of theText)) of theText
```

Answer (score 0):

Can even be simpler :D including a check for the user's input

```
set theText to text returned of (display dialog "newNameOfFolderDialogue" default answer "x")
if length of theText > 2 then --a safety check if the user has given the right answer
    tell theText to set {categoryOne, categoryTwo, categoryThree} to {character 1, character 2, text 3 thru -1}
else
    set {categoryOne, categoryTwo, categoryThree} to {null, null, null}
end if
```